# Can we have a report in karate containing the history of all the reports?

Tags: karate, automation-testing

For example: i ran some test cases today and generated a report and tomorrow i ran some more test cases and generated a report, is it possible to have a report having the history of all the reports i have generated before with the date mentioned on which they were generated?

Comment: if you use the cucumber output json, the CI/CD (e.g. Jenkins) plugins can do this for you